# How to run Pentaho console on linux from localhost:port/pentaho?

Tags: pentaho

I am trying to use pentaho which I downloaded from sourceforge (pentaho files). I run the schema-workbench shell correctly and a window opens with the interface, but I still haven't been able to connect to the admin console  on http://localhost:8080/pentaho.
Any ideas on which this doesn't seem to work for me?
Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `start-pentaho.sh` which launches (after a long the first time) the pentaho server on port 8080.

That is, if you have downloaded the correct package, because Pentaho contains many packages: one is the server, another one is the client-tools which contains the schema-workbench as well as the pdi (Pentaho Data Integrator), and the prd (Pentaho Report Designer) as well as few others.

Comment: I see, thanks. The shells I had downloaded are workbench.sh (with launches the schema workbench) and set-pentaho-env.sh, which apparently does nothing. I will look into other packages to download.

Answer (score 0):

You are running the wrong file. To open the pentaho console, you need to download the PNTAHO SERVER and run 'start-pentaho.sh'

Answer (score 0):

Pentaho by default will start PuC Pentaho USer Console on http://localhost:8080/pentaho once server is up and running. For getting the data integration i.e Spoon interface go to 
For Windows : Pentaho install directory>> design-tools>> data-integration>>spoon.bat
For Linux/Mac:Pentaho install directory>> design-tools>> data-integration>>spoon.sh

I hope this helps.